# DOM element not displaying when position:absolute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5. I have an element that is not displaying, under the following conditions:
1. Its CSS position is "absolute"
2. It is in the DOM under a JQM "grid":

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <div class="tt_autocomplete_wrap">
       <ul class="jqm_autocomplete ui-listview ...bla >
          <li class="ui-first-child" >
            <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" href="#">Not Seen If Absolute</a>
```

See the details here: http://jsfiddle.net/needlethread/kkpjq8ww/

If the CSS position of the .jqm_autocomplete element is set to "absolute", the first element in the demo does not display. I've left it displaying in the fiddle, but uncommenting the line shows the problem:

```
.jqm_autocomplete {
  /* uncomment the next line to see the problem */
  /*    position: absolute; */
```

However: it *is* positioned correctly - it can be seen using the developer tools in outline form, exactly where it should be. And its z-axis position is also in front of everything.

I can't see any difference in the computed styles of the working and non-working elements, but am I missing something?

**EDIT**: looks like one of them is getting clipped. Fiddle updated to show this clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/needlethread/kkpjq8ww/16/

Answer (score 1):

try commenting `position: relative` on its parent div css class ie: `<div class="tt_autocomplete_wrap">` and uncomment `position: absolute;`

on the CSS

```
.tt_autocomplete_wrap {
    /*position: relative;*/
}
```

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: That works - but why? The reasoning was that the _wrap was relative, so that the absolutely positioned ul would be placed relative to it (and not some other element higher up). Which worked - but why did it stop it displaying?

Comment: When it set to position:relative, div height is 0px, if you want to have it with position relative, add height: 54px; for that div

Comment: Thanks. I see now that it's being clipped by the relative div. Updated here to show the div size. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/needlethread/kkpjq8ww/14/). I guess that begs the question: why does only one of the elements get clipped? This dropdown can have any vertical size, so I need it to display "on top" of the rest of the page and not get clipped at all by other elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#element").show();
```